# Cantera problems in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, cantera

I try to start a program in Spyder. 
What I need to get start it is :

```
from Cantera import *
from Cantera.Reactor import *
from Cantera.Func import *
from Cantera import rxnpath
```

what I get is:

```
ImportError: No module named Cantera
```

and what I try so far is this:
First of all I read that it should be easy to install Anaconda to get Cantera started so I download it and start with

```
chmod +x ~/Downloads/Anaconda*.sh
~/Downloads/Anaconda*.sh
bash
conda update conda
conda install conda-build
conda update conda-build
conda install -c anaconda anaconda-navigator
conda create -n uni3.18 -c cantera cantera python=2.7 ipython matplotlib anaconda scipy
source activate uni3.18
```

so far I did what they say here http://www.cantera.org/docs/sphinx/html/install.html#id3

after that I start anaconda-navigator, see that my application is on uni3.18 and start Spyder. Start the program but it doesn't work.

I tried some other commands like

```
conda install -c cantera/label/dev cantera
```

or alone with

```
conda install -c cantera cantera
```

but in the end I didn't get it running. How can I import Cantera after installing it via conda?

Answer (score 0):

Cantera developer here. The reason is that the Cantera interface is imported with a lowercase c

```
import cantera
```

not a capital C.